# Swif struct not conform to Codable

Tags: swift, protocols, codable, swift-optionals

I'm trying to let a struct with optionals being codable/decodable but I receive an error message:

> Type 'item' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

here is the code:

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let domanda: String
    let rispostaSemplice: Int?
    var rispostaComplessa: [(testoRisposta: String, valoreRisposta: Bool)]?
}
```

How can I let `[(testoRisposta: String, valoreRisposta: Bool)]?` conform?

Thanks

Comment: You should make `(testoRisposta: String, valoreRisposta: Bool)` into another struct.

Comment: Tuples cannot be made to conform to Codable (see https://forums.swift.org/t/codable-tuples/14174). What does the JSON(?) for this look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
struct Item: Codable {
  let domanda: String
  let rispostaSemplice: Int?
  var rispostaComplessa: [InnerItem]?
}

struct InnerItem: Codable { 
   var testoRisposta: String
   var valoreRisposta: Bool
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can paste your JSON here, and get the struct of your JSON.

https://quicktype.io

There are more features regarding making a JSON object, which will help you in future.